# performSegueWithIdentifier not working on certain devices

Tags: ios, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

I am running into a problem which is entirely stumping me. performSegueWithIdentifier works perfectly fine on most devices, however when I run my program on an iPad with ios version 6.0 the segue is not happening.

Here is how my code works:

I call performSegue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"watchSegue" sender:self];
```

[image: Storyboard segue]
Which triggers initWithCoder of the destination view controller:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if ( self ) {

    }

    return self;
}
```

Which triggers prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  {   
  ...
}
```

This is where things differ. For all devices where this works, viewDidLoad of the destination view controller gets called:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
....
```

However with iPad iOS6.0 it does not get called and no segue is actually performed.

It's important to note that I do not actually have a different iPad app, I am simply running the iPhone app on the iPad, so the code and storyboard is identical.

------------UPDATE 1:
I just was able to reproduce this bug on a iPhone running 5.1.1. It is beyond me why my segues have been working all this time (and work in this version) and just in this one case they stop working...

-----------UPDATE 2:
This answer sadly won't give a greater understanding to this problem, nor stop it from happening again. I did however fix the problem.

By deleting the segue and adding it back in the storyboard, I was able to fix the problem. viewDidLoad now gets called and the segue is performed.

If someone has insight into what might have been going wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is 100% correct as it seems this is not documented in Apple, the view loading order of iOS6 has changed.

In iOS5, before :prepareForSegue is called, your destination view controller is ready and the view is loaded. But in iOS6, the destination view controller did not load the view yet. So if your code modifies any UI related stuff, it will not work on iOS6.

My solution to this is to call [destVC loadView] explicitly in :prepareForSegue

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found that I could actually reproduce this issue in iOS 5.1.1 as well. I don't totally understand why one particular segue wouldn't work, though I am investigating.

Comment: Just call loadView then, it won't hurt much... cause if the view is already loaded, it will return immd (lazy instantiation)